# Which schema should I use for city pages?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

I'm trying to determine which schema type to use for a business that's targeting searches that have a city on the search term.

The organization is an energy provider comparison site in which you can compare energy rates and plans and sign up for an energy plan.

The city pages were created to target searches with the city in the search query. Such as, electricity in Houston.

I'm confused as well with this one as to which schema type might be the best fit.

Comment: Not every page needs a schema.    Google only uses schema to power rich snippets.  If no rich snippet is available for that data type it isn't going to help SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example you provided, it looks like the intent of the article is to inform the user about various aspects regarding electricity within a city. In its current form, you probably don't need anything other than the standard article schema.

Nevertheless, if you want to add a schema to enhance your SERP visibility you probably want to look into the [FAQ schema](https://schema.org/FAQPage) for your pages. After all, your city article does answer questions about electricity and how to get it. You would want to restructure the headings to actually be Q&A and add a bit more Q&A content. You can get inspiration by taking the "People also ask" results and incorporating them in your content:

[image: electricity in Houston questions]

Once implemented and if Google picks it up you will end up taking up a lot more real estate for your target searches and it will make your content much more digestible. It will end up looking something like this:
[image: FAQ Schema Example]

I have used this for a few clients when they were targeting state and city keywords and have found that it generally helps with rankings and CTR if Google picks it up.